# Handle key press with textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, event-handling, keypress

I am trying to only allow the user to input numeric characters in a textbox however when I run the program it says

```
Unhandled exception at line 310, column 1 in Function code
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

It highlights keypresshandler(event).

Heres my code:

jquery.js

```
function myFunction() {

if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

}
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SortOrderTextBox" runat="server" Height="10px" Text='<%# Eval("SortOrder") %>' Font-Size="Small"/>
                    <input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for you:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

Change myFunction() to your function name, or whatever you're having it do.

Comment: I still got the same error. Am I suppose to change anything in the asp:TextBox?

Comment: you're supposed to add a function to the javaScript box, and tell it to do what you want it to.

Comment: Essentially what you're trying to do is: http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/3/ but have it run right after you press the key, or from the W3C: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup

Comment: I edited the code above. Its still giving the same error. Is there a way to handle e within the myFunction method when theres a key press?